# display autocomplete drop down list after based on keycode

Tags: jquery

i'm trying to use jquery-autocomplete library which I got from here https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete

here's the original code from the demo

```
$('#autocomplete').autocomplete({
        lookup: countriesArray,
        minChars: 0,
        onSelect: function (suggestion) {
            $('#selection').html('You selected: ' + suggestion.value + ', ' + suggestion.data);
        }
    });
```

but I need the drop down suggestion list to only be displayed after I entered the key @ (keycode 64), so here's what I did:

```
$('#autocomplete').keypress(function(event){
         var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);             

         if(keycode == 64){    //for @

            $('#autocomplete').autocomplete({
                lookup: countriesArray,
                minChars: 1,
                onSelect: function (suggestion) {
                    $('#selection').html('You selected: ' + suggestion.value + ', ' + suggestion.data + ', ' + keycodekeycode);
                }
             });
        }
    });
```

but the problem is now the drop-down list won't ever appear. no errors were also detected. however if I put something like

```
$('#autocomplete').keypress(function(event){
         var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);         
         var test = "1234";
         if(test== "1234"){    //for @

            $('#autocomplete').autocomplete({
                lookup: countriesArray,
                minChars: 1,
                onSelect: function (suggestion) {
                    $('#selection').html('You selected: ' + suggestion.value + ', ' + suggestion.data + ', ' + keycodekeycode);
                }
             });
        }
    });
```

the drop down suggestion list would appear without any problem. any idea what am I missing here?

tq

Comment: maybe because you must press '@' to perform autocomplete, and there's no result that can be found with char '@' in it. Maybe you can remove the char '@' after the keypress before autocomplete

Comment: dangggggggggg... that must be it! but how do I 'remove' the char @ from the searching parameter? because I sure don't want to remove the char @ from the text box

Comment: it's either by using Ajax lookup from jQuery plugin that you use, or try the non standard query/result from the page that you give. I don't know the result though if you use the non standard query/result from the plugin because I have never use that jQuery before. I myself prefer to use the Ajax lookup one though.

Answer (score 0):

Have you solve the problem yet? If no, here's the Fiddle for what you want [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3gCTU/)

After I read through the plugin, I found that you can manipulate the search query before finding the suggestion, so what you need is adding

```
lookupFilter: function(suggestion, query, queryLowerCase) {
if (showResult)
    return suggestion.value.indexOf(query.replace('@', '')) !== -1;
else
    return false
},
```

and if you see, my declaration for autocomplete is put outside because you only need to create the autocomplete once, and decide to show or not the result within the autocomplete itself

Comment: this thing doesn't really work, since it will remove the '@' in the input field, and the suggestion list would be displayed at the start of the input field, and removed all contents in it

Comment: what do you mean by 'it will remove the '@' in the input field', because the '@' still appear in the input field for me in the JSFIDDLE. And it didn't remove all content after displayed at the start of the input field, it filters it first whether there's a result that match input without the '@' or not. Did now you use a local suggestion or suggestion from jQuery, and have you solve it yet?